# ChartJS timeline graph with events

Tags: chart.js

[image]

I am trying to build a graph that would ressemble the one in the screenshot : it is a timeline on which events are displayed. 
But I need the spacing between events to correspond to actual time passing, therefore I believe I can not provide the events as X axis... so I really don't know what I should be looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to define the `xAxis` as a [time cartesian axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html). Then you can define the `data` of your dataset as [individual points](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#point) through objects containing `x` and `y` properties.

> Please note that Chart.js internally uses [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for the functionality of the [time axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html). Therefore you should use the [bundled version](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build) of Chart.js that includes Moment.js in a single file.

```js
const img = new Image(16, 16);
img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q94Tt.png'; 

var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [
        { x: "2020-03-22", y: 0 },
        { x: "2020-04-01", y: 0 },
        { x: "2020-04-02", y: 0 },
        { x: "2020-04-03", y: 0 },
        { x: "2020-04-08", y: 0 },
        { x: "2020-04-12", y: 0 },
        { x: "2020-04-15", y: 0 }
      ],
      pointStyle: img,
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          display: false,
        },        
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day',
          tooltipFormat: 'MMM DD'
        },
        gridLines: {
          display:false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="28"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation and the working example, this is exactly what I was after. Thanks again !

Comment: Update on this, values are shown on the line as follows : x: 2020-04-01, y:0 and I don't know why ! Would  you have any clue ?

Comment: Please post a new question for this new issue together with your code. Me or someone else may have an idea on how to solve this problem.

Comment: I actually did, sorry I could have linked. But I was able to actually solve it, the weird results I had where produced by the datalabels plugin. Thanks a bunch for your help !